# Why root user is not getting "Device or resource busy" response?

Tags: root, devices, modem

I am working with GSM modem and using `/dev/ttyUSB2` device.

Device is having proper rights:

```
$ ls -alh /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 2 May 25 19:44 /dev/ttyUSB2
```

I am in `dialout` group and I can send AT command to this modem only once. After sending "ATD" command (`echo -e -n "ATD ...;\r" > /dev/ttyUSB2`), according to `lsof /dev/ttyUSB2` process `ModemManager` opens this very file and if I send another AT command I get message:

```
bash: /dev/ttyUSB2: Device or resource busy
```

OK, so for some reason ModemManager is holding this file busy, but when this happens I can still send commands the same way, but from `root` user.

I've got two questions:

1. Why root user can override this "Device or resource busy" lock?
2. What rights / other settings regular user should have to bypass it like root user.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into a similar error using `wvdial` on Gentoo (with a properly configured kernel, `usb_modeswitch` set up, wvdial settings verified to work on another system, etc.). Just as you described, root could easily initialize the modem and connect to the Internet, whereas a user in the `dialout` group would get an error message very much like yours. The relevant device file was:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB2
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 2 Apr  6 01:43 /dev/ttyUSB2
```

The problem turned out to be that wvdial could not create a necessary lock file under `/run/lock`, which is owned by `root:uucp` on my system. After adding my regular user to `uucp`, the lock file could be created:

```
$ ls -la /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x  2 root uucp  80 Apr  6 01:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 520 Apr  6 01:44 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  foo   11 Apr  6 01:43 LCK..ttyUSB2
[...]
```

and the user was able to connect successfully, just like root. (In case you are wondering, `find / -group uucp` does not return anything other than that folder.)

I am not acquainted with `ModemManager` (nor used to writing to/reading from the device file directly), but given the similarity of our descriptions I suspect you might need to add your regular user to one more supplementary group. Try establishing a connection as root and check what additional files ModemManager touches; one of them (or a parent directory) may be at the root of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the code of [the `tty_reopen()` function in the Linux kernel sources](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.16/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L1359), itself called by `tty_open_current_tty()` itself called by `tty_open()` which is registered as the `open` function for tty file operations:

```
    if (test_bit(TTY_EXCLUSIVE, &tty->flags) && !capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN))
        return -EBUSY;
```

`EBUSY` is returned if the tty has been marked with `TTY_EXCLUSIVE` (via a `ioctl(TIOCEXCL)`) and the process is not capable of `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.

It's documented in the `tty_ioctl` man page:

> **Exclusive mode**
>
> `TIOCEXCL`  `void`
> Put the terminal into exclusive mode.  No further `open`(2) operations on the terminal are permitted.  (They fail with `EBUSY`, except for a process with the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`  capability.)
>
> `TIOCGEXCL` `int *argp`
> (since Linux 3.8) If the terminal is currently in exclusive mode, place a nonzero value in the location pointed to by argp; otherwise, place zero in *argp.
>
> `TIOCNXCL`  `void`
> Disable exclusive mode.

So here, `ModemManager` likely opened the device and called `ioctl(TIOCEXCL)` on it, so no other process other than those running as `root` (or have the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability) may open it.

You can see [it doing that `ioctl()` in its `port_connected()` function in the code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mobile-broadband/ModemManager/-/blob/a7bcf2036b34d5043dbc33fee7d98bae5859c4d3/src/mm-port-serial.c#L1116) with this comment:

```
    /* When the port is connected, drop the serial port lock so PPP can do
     * something with the port.  When the port is disconnected, grab the lock
     * again.
     */
```